# What's the fastest way to locate specific data in a large JSON?

Tags: jquery, node.js, json, jsonpath-plus

I have a JSON which can contain over a million records (each record is a simple object with some fields, but the heirarchy to get to it is contain about 5 levels). I need to find the records containing some values for the fields, preferably in a generic way in node.js.

I tried [jsonpath-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) which does exactly what I want. The problem is that processing that much data takes about 25 seconds (if I return only the data, without the path, it takes 10s).

I tried [json_query](https://libraries.io/npm/json_query) (which is an adaptation of DOJO JSonQuery to node.js). This is working really fast (1s) but only returns the data and not the path to the data.

I was wondering if you can think of alternatives I can use or how can I make jsonpath-plus work faster.

Clarification: I don't generate the data. I receive it with no way of controlling that. I receive the full JSON blob and then I have to perform a few (about 5) queries on it before I get a new one.

Sincerely,
Elad

Comment: Any solution here is simply a workaround for the main problem; weight of data. It's really not a good idea to have a million-record JSON file as a live datastore. I'd suggest using a better more scalable solution, ie. a database.

Comment: You definitely should be using a database for this volume of data. Writing an optimized query for a JSON blob that large will still require a full scan on every query. This is the value of a database; indexing segments of your data. The alternative would be writing a chained filter that keys on a specific value at each level, which is likely slower than what jsonpath-plus offers. For comparison, even an optimized MongoDB document starts to lag at the third level of nesting.

Comment: Clarification: I don't generate the data, I receive it with no way to control that. I could put it in a DB, but doing so will have an indexing penalty and I receive new data (which replaces the old one) often (I will only get to do few queries before I have to re-insert the data in the DB)

Answer (score 0):

> Clarification: I don't generate the data. I receive it with no way of controlling that.

But, you could load it into a database and have it generate an index for you, pre-optimized for the queries you need.  (Alternatively, you could build such an index in your own application.)

> I receive the full JSON blob and then I have to perform a few (about 5) queries on it before I get a new one.

You'll have to determine whether or not building an index to run these queries is worth it.  If you're only doing 5 queries, and they require a full search of the data, then it might be faster just to slog through it the way you are now.

One other thought... is this line-delimited JSON where each record is its own object?  If so, you could parallelize this searching.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the json_query code to return the path. Adding caching made it work even faster (~200ms per query).

As for all the suggestions to use a DB:
I am well aware of the merits of using a DB, but I think that for my specific use case, it isn't worth the trouble.
The size I stated earlier is a worst case scenario (by far). I usually expect to have 50K records. Even so, and as demonstrated by the json_query package, running a full scan on 1M records should not be a problem for modern computers.